# ¿Se puede cargar un reporte de crystal report sin necesidad de una ruta y el archivo fisico C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Deseo cargar un reporte de crystal report desde el codigo pero sin una ruta especificada y sin tener el archivo .rpt fisico ejemplo:

```
String user, pass, host, catalog;
user = "UsuarioBD"
pass = "1234"
host = "SERVIDOR"
catolog = "NOMBRE_BD"
private ReportDocument crystalrpt;
crystalrpt = new ReportDocument();
crystalrpt.Load("Nombre_del_reporte.rpt");
crystalrpt.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(host, catalog, user, pass);
crystalrpt.SetParameterValue("@fecha", fecha);
crystalrpt.SetParameterValue("@arcid", identifica);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalrpt;
```

Esto con fines de seguridad ya que si se maneja un archivo físico en una ruta especifica este es vulnerable a modificaciones por parte de personas con conocimiento en programación.

Comment: Lo normal en estos casos es poner el informe como recurso incrustado, de esa manera no es un archivo separado sino que está incrustado en el archivo de recursos

Comment: Como harias la definicion del rpt si no esta en un archivo?

Comment: @Pikoh y como hago para poner el archivo incrustado si reviso en las propiedades del reporte el ya aparece como recurso incrustado. no se si te refieres a eso o a otra forma

Comment: @gbianchi no entiendo tu comentario, me explicas mejor?? gracias